# How would I create a String using a Character array in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, char, character

What would be the most efficient way to construct a new String using a `Character[]`? It's easy enough to do with the primitive `char[]`, but unfortunately the String constructor does not include an option for `Character[]`. Converting to a `char[]` seems cumbersome. Is there any efficient way to construct the String with just the `Character[]`?

Thanks.

Comment: `StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder(chars.length())` followed by a loop whose body calls `s.append` is as efficient as you’re likely to get.  Any shorter solutions will be doing the equivalent at best.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One solution is to use a [`Stream`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html) with [`Collectors#joining`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#joining()):

```
Character[] chars = { 'H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o' };

String s = Arrays.stream(chars)
                 .map(Object::toString)
                 .collect(Collectors.joining());

System.out.println(s);
```

Output:

```
Hello
```

Answer (score 0):

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package javaapplication2;

public class as {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Character[] chars = {'T', 'e', 'c', 'h', 'i', 'e', ' ',
            'D', 'e', 'l', 'i', 'g', 'h', 't'};

        StringBuilder word=new StringBuilder();
        for (Character char1 : chars) {
            word.append(char1);
        }
        System.out.println(word);
    }

}
```

Comment: The question is asking about `Character[]`, not `char[]`.

Answer (score 0):

One way of converting `Character` array to `String`

```
Character[] chars = { 'H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o' };

String str = Stream.of(chars)
             .map(String::valueOf)
             .collect(Collectors.joining());

System.out.println(str);
```

**Ouput:**

```
Hello
```

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any efficient way to construct the String with just the `Character[]`?

No.  There are no constructors which can do that.

The most efficient approach is likely to be converting it to `char[]` as you yourself suggested:

```
char[] chars = new char[characters.length];
for (int i = characters.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    chars[i] = characters[i];
}
String s = String.valueOf(chars);
```

Remember that “efficient” does not mean “stuffed into one line.”  A Stream-based solution is going to be less efficient, because it will create (and eventually garbage-collect) a String for each Character.